# Can I say "I have some apprehensions"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can I say "I have some apprehensions"? Or it should always be in singular.

For example,

"He seems to be able to walk now, but I have some apprehensions that he can faint at any time"

Google search gives me both, but I am not sure if both of them are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd only use *apprehensions* if there was more than one reason I was apprehensive.

> I'm not sure I want my daughters to go camping this weekend.  The weather is supposed to be terrible, I'm not sure their old enough to handle a weekend by themselves, and there's been a rash of crime at the park. Besides, they're exhausted from swim practices all week – I have several apprehensions about this trip.

Such a usage would be rare, however.  I'd usually be inclined to group all those worries and concerns together, and say, "I have *much apprehension* about this trip."

FWIW, a half-century search in Google books returned [less than a dozen results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20have%20some%20apprehensions%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1950,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22I%20have%20some%20apprehensions%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&sa=X&ei=XiwqUMndBcrJyAGMhYC4Cw&ved=0CC4QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3alang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1950,cd_max:12/31/2000&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=7579ccdccb82fcf6&biw=1675&bih=870).

Comment: There's no real reason to use the singular. "I have apprehensions" is actually more common than "I have an apprehension", according to [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+apprehension%2Chave+apprehensions%2Chave+an+apprehension%2Chave+some+apprehensions%2Chave+apprehension&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=10). People just don't always put in the unnecessary determiner *"some"*.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of those sounds normal.  Usually you just say that you’re ***apprehensive*** about something.

Otherwise, use the plural not the singular, and say you have some apprehension***s***.

Comment: And I'd say, "that he *could* faint at any time." meaning it's a possibility whereas "can faint" implies a capability.

Comment: @Jim Or *may* or *might*, depending.

Comment: @tchrist- Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you'd probably use a different word, perhaps "concerned" or "worried."  And "can faint" should be "could faint".  We're not expressing that he is *able* to faint, but rather that he *might* faint.

So I'd say, "He seems to be able to walk now, but I'm concerned that he could faint at any time."

Answer (score 1):

How about something less clinical. For example, "He recovered well enough to start walking again. Every early step he took made me tremble with fear he may fall. Outwardly I smiled uncomfortably, acknowledging his progress."